# Is it correct to say "It was he I was talking about"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Is it correct to say

> "It was he I was talking about"?

If it isn't, how should I say that? I also suppose it would be correct to say

> It was he (him) who I was talking about.

Comment: "He" is very formal and hardly ever heard; just about everyone says "him". In any case, the pronoun is the object of the preposition "about" in the relative clause where accusative "him" is required. Btw, there is no rule requiring a nominative form where the pronoun is complement of "be", so don't worry about breaking some rule by using "him", because there isn't one!

Comment: I'd say that "he" is so formal that the sentence could easily be formed as "It was he of whom I was speaking".

Comment: It's grammatically correct but as others have noted, nobody talks like that.  A common way to say it would be "He was the person I was talking about" or "He was the one I was talking about".